# Make first tab active by default

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am using the following html snippet.

1.) How i can make the general tab active by default. I tried to add active class but than somehow the first one is only active every time.

2.) Once i click the tabs and if i reload the page I get the following error and the whole page seems to break. the url falls back to base url

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DataConfigurationGeneralDetailComponent'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DataConfigurationGeneralDetailComponent'
```

HTML

```
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                data-toggle="tab"
                [routerLink]="['general']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                role="tab" dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.tabs.general">General</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab"
                [routerLink]="['mapping']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.tabs.mappings">Mappings</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab"
                [routerLink]="['target']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                dpTranslate="dataconfiguration.tabs.target">Target</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
           <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
```

ROUTES

```
export const tenantRoute: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'tenant',
        component: TenantComponent,
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'tenant.home.title'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: TenantDetailComponent,
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                    pageTitle: 'tenant.home.title'
                },

            },
            {
                path: ':id/dataconfiguration/:id',
                component: DataConfigurationDetailComponent,
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                    pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title'
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'general',
                        component: DataConfigurationGeneralDetailComponent,
                        data: {
                            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                            pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'mapping',
                        component: DataConfigurationMappingDetailComponent,
                        data: {
                            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                            pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'target',
                        component: DataConfigurationTargetDetailComponent,
                        data: {
                            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                            pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** *updated with routes example to address comment on answer.*

To answer your first question, to make the general tab always the default tab, you would set the '**catch all( * )**' route to point to the General tab component.

See here for usage of the `routerLinkActive` directive: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html

To address your second question, ensure you are using the correct imports in your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

and you are using forRoot, e.g.

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routesArrayGoesHere)
```

**-- Updated content**

An example of a simple routing config would be like below.

`path: ''` is the url when no parameters are defined, this is route you wish to utilise to load up the general tab first, so you would point this to the 'general tab' component.

The `path: '**'` route is technically the catch all when it cannot find a route, in this case I have this going to an error page.

`const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
 ]`

You've made your routing more complex by nesting children in it. I would suggest getting your routing working with flat paths first, then experiment later. ie.
One thing to note, I've used **Routes**, instead of **Route[]** (probably the same thing, but something to try changing if still having issues).

`export const tenantRoute: Route[] = [
    { path: 'tenant', component: TenantComponent,
      data: { authorities: ['ROLE_USER'], pageTitle: 'tenant.home.title' },
    },
    { path: 'tenant:id', component: TenantDetailComponent,
      data: { authorities: ['ROLE_USER'], pageTitle: 'tenant.home.title' },
    },
    { path: 'tenant:id/dataconfiguration/:id', component: DataConfigurationDetailComponent,
      data: { authorities: ['ROLE_USER'], pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title' }
    },
    { path: 'tenant:id/dataconfiguration/:id/general', component: DataConfigurationGeneralDetailComponent,
      data: { authorities: ['ROLE_USER'], pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title' }
    },
    { path: 'tenant:id/dataconfiguration/:id/mapping', component: DataConfigurationMappingDetailComponent,
      data: { authorities: ['ROLE_USER'], pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title' }
    },
    { path: 'tenant:id/dataconfiguration/:id/target', component: DataConfigurationTargetDetailComponent,
      data: { authorities: ['ROLE_USER'], pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title' }
    }
];`

Comment: I put the route table also. Where should i put the catch all( * )

Answer (score 0):

This is not done in the template, but in the routing configuration.

You need to redirect to your general tab by default :

```
{ path: ':id', component: MyPageComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'general', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'general', component: MyGeneralTabComponent },
]},
```

in your case, it means that when you navigate to '/tenant/123/dataconfiguration/456/', you will be automatically redirected to '/tenant/123/dataconfiguration/456/general', and routing will load the correct component in your router-outlet.

edit: You seem to have a problem in your routing configuration, you redefine :id, it's already defined once at parent level.

```
{
    path: 'dataconfiguration/:id', // remove first :id, it's already defined in parent route
    component: DataConfigurationDetailComponent,
    data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
        pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title'
    },
    children: [
        // Add default redirect here
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'general', pathMatch: 'full' },
        {
            path: 'general',
            component: DataConfigurationGeneralDetailComponent,
            data: {
                authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title'
            }
        },
        {
            path: 'mapping',
            component: DataConfigurationMappingDetailComponent,
            data: {
                authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title'
            }
        },
        {
            path: 'target',
            component: DataConfigurationTargetDetailComponent,
            data: {
                authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                pageTitle: 'dataconfiguration.home.title'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So till i get to general tab my path looks like following http://localhost:8080/#/tenant/58a958f26226ba36904b9e71/dataconfiguration/58a959616226ba36904b9e72/ - The numbers are dynamic. Now your suggestion path i can see empty from where i want to redirect.

Comment: With the redirectPath, it means that when you go to page "/tenant/12345", you will be automatically redirected to "/tenant/12345/general". Now that you've added routes, I'll update my answer.